# How do I display an array that I have created in NodeJS in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays

Ok, so I am fairly new to this stuff so I'll try to be as cohesive as I can with my problem.

I have created a simple web scraper using NodeJS, Express and Axios. This web scraper scrapes text from a class on a defined URL and passes the results in the console as a string using JSON.stringify.

The problem I am having, is I cannot work out a way to display this array text on a HTML page in a p tag.

For now, I have removed the URL and classnames as I want to keep what I am doing fairly low key, but I have replaced it with uppercase text. The MY URL GOES HERE is the URL of the site I am scraping from, and the CLASSNAME is the name of the specific class I am pulling text from.

Node JS index.js file:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const url = 'MY URL GOES HERE'
app.use('/', express.static('index.html'))

axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const textArray = []

        $('.CLASSNAME', html).each(function() {
            const myTextArray = $(this).text()
            textArray.push({
                myTextArray
            })
        })
        const finalResult = JSON.stringify(textArray)
        console.log(finalResult)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`))
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="headline">This is the ingredients list</h1>
<p class="array"></p>

<script>

    var results = document.getElementsByClassName('array')
    console.log(results)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how to get the array from the NodeJS js file and show it within the p tag within my HTML file.

I tried to install Puppeteer as I read this allows NodeJS to use standard JS commands in the DOM but I was getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/MYNAME/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/88/53
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/MYNAME/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/88/53'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/MYNAME/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/88/53
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/MYNAME/.npm/_logs/2023-12-15T01_00_27_889Z-debug-0.log
```

I am very new to this, so if I have missed anything or you need any extra context please let me know and I'll do my best to provide information where I can.

Comment: Side question: why use axios? Node's had native Fetch support for a while now, no need for a third party library to get data from URLs. Not so side-question: what is that axios call _for_? Because right now it runs on startup, and then it's gone, It's running "before your server even starts". If you want it to run when people request a URL, make an `app.get` route handler, and use a templating engine (you're in express, so EJS is the built-in choice, but there are others) and save your axios result as a global that you can then tell the templating engine to use as part of rendering a page.

Comment: In all honesty, I was following a tutorial from a couple years ago as I just wanted to try and get a web scraper built. If there is a better way to do this, I am happy to learn if you have a URL or code snippet to get started. The web scraper itself works, but it's the conversion to HTML that has my head in a spin.

Comment: start by _saving_ your URL's result (and to make your own life easier, using await, rather than .then/.catch) so that you actually have a variable that you can refer to in your `app.get(`/`, (req, res) => { res.render("index", { data: thethingyoucannowuse }); });`. Lots of good tutorials that explain how to use the latest express with a current version of Node out there to find, too.

Comment: Would this look something like this:

`app.get('/index', function routeHandler(req, res) {
  res.send('ok');
});`

Apologies for the noob questions, I'm just trying my best to learn on the fly here.

Comment: I shall check out this a bit more - the `data : thingyoucannowuse` - is this referring to the data I am scraping? Specifically the class name I am pulling data from?

Comment: Learning on the fly is unfortunately not what SO is for, though. Don't use the plain `.send`, use `.render` with a templating engine, and not that you know about those terms, look up a tutorial on how to do that because teaching how to do that properly is beyond the scope of an SO post. SO is not for learning how to use a new thing, it's your last resort for solving problems that you can't solve after having looked for how to do things on the web in general (docs, tutorials, etc)

Comment: OK will do. Thanks for that tidbit of info. It's kinda late here so I'll read up more on this tomorrow for sure. In regards to the HTML side, is there something I am missing there? I thought I'd just be able to pull in the js file and then start calling the const's from there but when I run it in Chrome it's just a blank page minus my H1.

Comment: You can't load Node-specific .js code into the browser. Instead, the usual solution is to have the browser "ask the server for the data" using a URL on the client, and a special route handler on the server side, or by templating it directly into your page(s) so that you don't need JS at all on the client side, with the page simply "already having everything it needs" when it loads.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into this.

Comment: Go find another tutorial on how to render a webpage using a node server. When that works as expected, add your scraper into the mix such that the server calls the scraping logic then returns that output into the HTML returned to the client.

Comment: I shall. I am a designer by trade that has coded HTML, CSS and some JS in the past but it has been a few years now so I'd like to get back into it. I appreciate the time you've spent here helping me - I never intended on this being a full on learning experience but it definitely seems to have gone that way. I'll make sure to use SO for fully developed questions in the future. Thanks again to the both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you import index.js in your html ,it's a little scary,index.js can
only run by node ,it's your service in localhost,I hope you can understand the code I modified below

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`))
const url = 'MY URL GOES HERE'
app.use('/', express.static('index.html'))
app.get('/getArray', (req, res) => {
    axios(url)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            const textArray = []
            $('.CLASSNAME', html).each(function () {
                const myTextArray = $(this).text()
                textArray.push({
                    myTextArray
                })
            })
            const finalResult = JSON.stringify(textArray)
            console.log(finalResult)
            res.send(finalResult)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="headline">This is the ingredients list</h1>
    <p class="array"></p>

    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:your express port';
        axios.get('/getArray')
            .then(function (response) {
                var results = response.data
                console.log(results)
                document.querySelector('.array').innerHTML = results
            })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```